# Not working getComponentEnableSetting() in Android Test Project

Tags: android, testing

I have an android test project with some tests. When I run this tests in separated project, one test has error like this:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown component: ComponentInfo{com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher.Launcher}`

But if I use folder `tests` into my testing project this test work fine. Can you answer me please, what I need do for normal working in both cases?

Code of this test:

```java
public void testDisableComponent() {
    PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName("com.android.launcher", "com.android.launcher.Launcher");
    assertNotNull(pm.getComponentEnabledSetting(componentName));
    assertNotNull(componentName);
}
```

Thanks for yours answers.

**P.S.**: I can write all code of this test project, if it's need.